# Calling React setState hook from outside react (DOM/Google Maps)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building a function React component which uses various `useState()` hooks. Each of them providing a state and a function which can be called to update it. This works beautifully from within react itself. But in my scenario I have to deal with other (DOM/Google Maps) environments as well.

As a callback from a DOM element put on the Google map, I want to call `setState(!state)` to flip a boolean. However, this works only once.

I think that the problem is that the setState hook fails to fetch the latest state but uses the initial state instead. Flipping a bool 1 will invert it, but the flipping it again without taking the former change into account does not update anything.

I've managed to solve this by implementing a state that sets the boolean on a data attribute in the DOM (and then flip that bool) but I think that's a rather ugly solution.

How should I update the state in functional React component from a callback function provided by something not React?

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates).

```
const [bool, setBool] = React.useState(false);

// Flip bool depending on latest state.
setBool((prevBool) => !prevBool);
```

As opposed to using the latest state in the component itself, which can use the wrong state depending on the memoization / state life cycle:

```
const [bool, setBool] = React.useState(false);

// bool could be behind here. DON'T do this.
setBool(!bool);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is `setState` using the wrong state, you can pass a function to `setState` instead:

```
setState(state => !state);
```

This will use the latest state instead of the state which occurred at the React render. Not sure how this will play with the weird outside-of-React situation here, but it may help out. If this page isn't even using React (the component with the state you want to edit isn't even rendered) then HTML LocalStorage might be your best bet for persisting information.